# Which characters are forbidden for naming files and how to remove them?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an audio recorder application. When user has finished recording audio, he is asked to rename the file. I know that there are some forbidden characters that aren't allowed to be in a file name.

Can I find a full list of those forbidden characters for android anywhere? I found a list for windows, are they the same for android?

And once I get the list, how do I "forbid" them from the android keyboard? Well, weither literally remove them from the keyboard or just simply display an error when one of those keys is intered. I'd appreciate any kind of info/help.

Comment: Special characters. How do you forbid them ? Well, check the text when it is entered using `TextChangeListener` and see if the user entered those characters

Comment: Not sure if this is true but makes kind of sense: http://serverfault.com/a/150745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android as typical Linux system, uses at least a few different file systems. Execute `mount` command on device to see them. It is at least `yaffs2` or `ext3`, `tmpfs`, `vfat`. They all have different policies about naming files, especially when it comes to `vfat` (sdcard). One name can be created on `yaffs` or `tmpfs` but it will not be allowed on `vfat`.

I think it would be good strategy to try to create file with a given name and check for failure.

Other strategy would be compiling the greatest common set of disallowed characters from all files systems you can expect on Android. Use this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_comparison#Limits).